# pgAdmin does not open in AWS EC2

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-ec2, pgadmin-4

I am trying to deploy Django based website on AWS EC2. I have successfully created an instance and install my python libraries there. I am using Postgres here. For that, I have installed Postgres along with pgAdmin, but for some reason, it does not open. It just displayed that it's starting up the server but it does not open at all.

[image]

I am new to it so I do not know much about it. Can someone please help or guide me why it does not open up?

Comment: When you say open, do you mean it doesn't open a web browser window after starting or the server does not start at all?

Comment: Is there an elephant in the system tray?  Can you view the logs?

Comment: @Danoram It doesn't open up a web browser window at all. It does show the icon in my taskbar that it's running but as soon as I hover over it, it disappears hence shutdown I guess.

Comment: @jjanes It does show the icon in my taskbar that it's running but as soon as I hover over it, it disappears hence shutdown I guess. And no, I cannot find the logs. I think they didn't get created since it doesn't open up even once.

Comment: I've had this problem before, and the only solution I found (other than not use pgadmin4) was to completely remove it and reinstall it.  Never did figure out the root cause.

Comment: @jjanes I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both (Postgresql and pgAmin) but it still doesn't work. I did manage to find logs though, here are the images link of the logs: http://championdumpster.esquall.com/assets/img/startup.PNG and http://championdumpster.esquall.com/assets/img/Other.PNG

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the logs from

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local with name - 'pgadmin4.startup'

A lot of the time removing the instance and recreating usually works but without seeing the logs it's hard to tell what the issue might be. Could also be worth making the instance a bit beefier as pgadmin does use a good amount of CPU and memory.

Comment: Not sure why it happens but recreating an instance does the trick.